# On scroll up use the animate() and show the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two navigation in my website. Both the navigation bars are fixed. Basically when I scroll up, I would like to use the animate() and show both the navigation bar in the page. How do I get the scroll up event and use that to animate the divs, like the Google search widget. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

html:

```
    <div id="navbar_header">
        <a href="#">some link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main_content">
        <p>Some content...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar_footer">
        <a href="#">some link</a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#navbar_header {
    background: #22313F;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

#navbar_footer {
    background: #22313F;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: please define what you mean by 'scroll up' further. like when someone scrolls all the way down first, and then after reaching the bottom goess all the way back up?

Comment: @YourConscious No, I don't want scroll to top function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally using the window for the scroll event should be sufficient, as it's big enough and the one element, that's being scrolled. If jQuery is loaded correctly, you could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastTopPosition = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var topPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (topPosition > lastTopPosition ){
            $("#navbar_header").stop(true).animate({'top':'-40px'}, 200);
            $("#navbar_footer").stop(true).animate({'bottom':'-40px'}, 200);
        } else {
            $("#navbar_header").stop(true).animate({'top':'0px'}, 200);
            $("#navbar_footer").stop(true).animate({'bottom':'0px'}, 200);
        }
        lastTopPosition = topPosition;
    }
});
```

This piece of code gets the current position from the top everytime you scroll. If the distance gets bigger (scroll down) the two bars fadeout. If it's getting smaller (scroll up) it fades in. You can replace the FadeOut/In methods here with you animate() call too. A check, if the elements are displayed would be good here too, but I guess you can figure that one out ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I have changed your given code with something like this to hide: `$("#navbar_header").animate({'top':'-40px'}, 200);` and to show `$("#navbar_header").animate({'top':'0px'}, 200);`. But its responding very slow, I mean when I scroll up it animates after sometime. Why is it?

Comment: As the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) points out the 2nd parameter given to the animate function determines the duration, unit is millisecond here. So if you're changing your 200 from above to a smaller number, it's animating faster.

Comment: No. What I meant was, I think its getting the event after sometime. Because even if I change the duration to say 50, the animation is fast, but the animation starts after sometime. Hope I was clear.

Comment: i see the problem. The next animate() method is called before the former is done. You need the stop() function here with the first parameter set to true (clears the queue), I've edited my answer, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/KHeZY/159/) the fiddle if anybody needs it ;-)

Comment: Yes! Now its better. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right, something along the lines of:

```
$("#main_content").scroll(function(){
     $('#navbar_header').show(300); 
     $('#navbar_footer').show(300); 
});
```

Where show(300) will basically do a 300ms showing animation of your divs.

Comment: Is there a parent element\frame that would be better responsible for handling the scroll function, possibly?

Comment: No there's no parent element.